# Proof of Kolmogorov zero-one law in measure-theoretic setting

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

I have met, in some paper, the following form of the Kolmogorov zero-one law used:

> If $A\subseteq 2^\Bbb N$ is a subset of Cantor space such that when $x,y\in 2^\Bbb N$ are such that $x,y$ differ on finitely many places, then $x\in A\Leftrightarrow y\in A$, and $A$ is measurable, then $A$ has measure $0$ or $1$.

I wanted to find a proof if this statement, but no probabilistic proof of the law seems to be applicable in direct way here. I wanted to point out that I don't know much about measure theory, so I would love to have the proof explained in relatively simple terms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand the probabilistic proof, and merely want to know how the statement above translates into the probabilistic 0-1 law?